# MeteorJS: Store/Call MongoDB Document Size (bsonsize)

Tags: meteor

In my MeteorJS app, documents grow very rapidly. When documents reach the 16MB, standard document size limit in MongoDB, my application starts erroring, notifying me that the document size is too large to perform any more updates to the document:

`exception: BSONObj size: 16895320 (0xEEEEEEEE) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB)`

To prevent my application from reaching this state of error, I want to be able to lookup the size (bsonsize) of a the document ahead of time. If the bsonsize is above, say 15.8MB, create a new document and start logging data there. This way, no errors will be encountered.

Using the Mongo Shell, bsonsize can be determined via: `Object.bsonsize(db.collection.findOne({_id:'document id here'}))`. But Object.bsonsize() does not appear to be supported by Meteor within javascript:

`TypeError: Object function Object() { [native code] } has no method 'bsonsize'`

How can this be done in javascript/MeteorJS? Thanks!

Comment: If your documents are typically getting close to the [maximum document size](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#BSON-Document-Size) (currently 16Mb as at MongoDB 2.6), this is likely a signal that your schema is not optimal. Documents that grow in size frequently will generate additional disk I/O as they outgrow their current record allocation, and can lead to storage fragmentation if the space cannot be effectively reused. For more background, see the documentation on [Operational Factors and Data Models](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-model-operations/).

Comment: Also relevant, see: [Why shouldn't I embed large arrays in my documents?](http://askasya.com/post/largeembeddedarrays).

Comment: I forgot to ask .. are you trying to call `bsonsize()` via MiniMongo or the native MongoDB driver? The Node driver has [`calculateobjectsize()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/bson.html#bson-calculateobjectsize). I would still reconsider your schema, but calculating BSON size might be useful for document storage/growth estimation.

Comment: Hey @Stennie - I've begun designing a new schema to reduce document size, thank you for the links and information. However, I'd still like to have this document size code handy so that I can further constrain document growth in my app. I was trying to call `bsonsize()` in my server-side javascript code but was receiving the `has no method bsonsize()` error. I tried `calculateobjectsize(doc-obj-here)` but received error `ReferenceError: calculateobjectsize is not defined`. How do I define it? You mentioned driver, is there an add-on to Node that I need to install? I'm on Node `v0.10.24`. Thanks